# ELK - How to match http request and response and store it as a single line of record?

Tags: elk

I have seen a log in Kibana where the http request and response was displayed in a single line/record.

My Kibana setup currently displays the request and response in separate lines/records.

How do i customize and ultimately achieve this?

Comment: does this capability comes from the "multiline" codec?

Answer (score 0):

"Multiline" codec is the tool for this.